# Apply CSS to a group of HTML tags before reaching a certain class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a group of list tags inside of an unordered list such as:

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li class="active">4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to target all of the list elements before or after the active class via CSS?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can target all of the sibling elements **after** with `~`

```
li.active ~ li
{
    color: green;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vLhsjy39/)

---

In CSS, you cannot target siblings prior to an element, so you would have to do something like this:

Give them all a rule:

```
li
{
    color: orange;
}
```

Then overwrite the active one

```
li.active
{
    color: red;
}
```

Then overwrite the ones after

```
li.active ~ li
{
    color: green;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vLhsjy39/1/)

Comment: So easy, love it! thanks :)

Comment: This answer reminds me of Phoenix Wright somehow... turning the problem on its head to solve it...

Answer (score 1):

Just to point it out, another way could be:

```
li:not(.active) {
  /* your css rules here */
}
```

This will select every `li` who doesn't have the class `.active`

Comment: This would select those before and after.  If you want before xor after, you'd need something else.